# forrmatting date in command line output

Tags: command-line, bash, timestamp

This will be a very dumb question to the gurus I'm guessing but here goes.

I am trying to keep track of the number of threads on my system and I need to add timestamp somewhere with each output.

Here is my current command to check number of threads :

```
watch -n1 'ps -eLo pid,cmd,nlwp | wc -l >> test.txt'
```

I would like the timestamp to be added on each line in `test.txt` as the number of threads gets written

How do I get the output to look like `2020-12-14 07:08:10 5431` (where 5431 is the number of threads) ?

Comment: Use `ts` or one of the many options involving `date` from the dupe

Comment: I am certain that there are ones out there a lot cleaner than this one, but it seems to work: `watch -n 1 'printf "$(date +%F" "%T" ")" >> test.txt; ps -eLo pid,cmd,nlwp | wc -l >> test.txt'`

Comment: printf can handle date format `printf '%(%F %T)T %s\n' now "$(ps -eLo pid,cmd,nlwp | wc -l)"`, but I think like muru `ts` is a good choice